# Issue running python script from c++

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to make a program that can grade the output of a python program. I am missing something simple but I keep getting a seg fault for trying to turn the output into a string. Works fine if I leave it a char* but I want a string so I can compare the output in the future.
Here is the code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string runPython(const char* filename) {
    string cmd = "python " + string(filename);
    char* buf;
    FILE* in = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    fscanf(in,"%s", buf);
    string res(buf);
    pclose(in);
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc > 1) {  
        string res = runPython(argv[1]);
        printf("%s", res.c_str());
    }
    else {
        printf("\e[31mNo File Submitted for Grading\e[0m\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allocate the buffer first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_READ 4096

string runPython(const char* filename) {
    string cmd = "python " + string(filename);
    char* buf = new char[MAX_READ]; // buffer allcoation
    FILE* in = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    fscanf(in,"%s", buf);
    string res(buf);
    delete[] buf; // buffer release
    pclose(in);
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc > 1) {  
        string res = runPython(argv[1]);
        printf("%s", res.c_str());
    }
    else {
        printf("\e[31mNo File Submitted for Grading\e[0m\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```